# Device tree: no pinctrl handle

Tags: linux, tree, kernel, overlay, device

I trying to add overlay with RTC PCF8563 support to my Yocto build for Raspberry PI 4-b. I have prepared DT overlay:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

#include <dt-bindings/pinctrl/bcm2835.h>
#include <dt-bindings/gpio/gpio.h>

/ {

     compatible = "raspberrypi,4-model-b", "brcm,bcm2711";

     fragment@1 {
     target = <&i2c0mux>;
     __overlay__ {
         #address-cells = <1>;
         #size-cells = <0>;
         status = "okay";
         pinctrl-names = "default";
         pinctrl-0 = <&i2c0_pins>;

      };
   };

   fragment@2 {

      target = <&i2c0>;
      __overlay__ {
         status = "okay";

         pcf8563: pcf8563@51 {
            compatible = "nxp,pcf8563";
            reg = <0x51>;
            status = "okay";
        };

    };

};

fragment@3 {
    target = <&i2c0if>;
    __overlay__ {
        status = "okay";
        clock-frequency = <50000>;
    };
};

fragment@4 {
    target = <&i2c1>;
    __overlay__ {
        status = "okay";
    };
 };
```

};

i2c0mux node is a parent of i2c0 node.

I have also enable id Kconfig below options:

**CONFIG_I2C_MUX_PINCTRL=y**

**CONFIG_RTC_DRV_PCF8563=y**

But I get an error:

```
root@super-pi-machine:~# dmesg | grep pcf
[    0.155459] bus: 'i2c': add driver pcf857x
[    9.003364] bus: 'i2c': add driver rtc-pcf8563
[   10.419959] bus: 'i2c': __driver_probe_device: matched device 0-0051 with driver rtc-pcf8563
[   10.419982] bus: 'i2c': really_probe: probing driver rtc-pcf8563 with device 0-0051
[   10.420022] rtc-pcf8563 0-0051: no pinctrl handle
[   10.420486] rtc-pcf8563 0-0051: pcf8563_write_block_data: err=-121 addr=0e, data=03
[   10.428359] rtc-pcf8563 0-0051: pcf8563_probe: write error
[   10.434098] rtc-pcf8563: probe of 0-0051 failed with error -5
```

I have decompiled /sys/firmware/base/devicetree from target hardware to check how exactly looks device tree:

```
i2c0 {
    brcm,pins = <0x00 0x01>;
    phandle = <0xa7>;
    brcm,pull = <0x02>;
    brcm,function = <0x04>;
};
. . .
. . .
i2c0mux {
        compatible = "i2c-mux-pinctrl";
        pinctrl-1 = <0x12>;
        status = "okay";
        #address-cells = <0x01>;
        i2c-parent = <0x10>;
        #size-cells = <0x00>;
        phandle = <0x35>;
        pinctrl-0 = <0xa7>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";

        i2c@0 {
            status = "okay";
            #address-cells = <0x01>;
            #size-cells = <0x00>;
            phandle = <0xb2>;
            reg = <0x00>;
            pinctrl-0 = <0xa7>;
            pinctrl-names = "default";

            pcf8563@51 {
                compatible = "nxp,pcf8563";
                status = "okay";
                phandle = <0xec>;
                reg = <0x51>;
            };
        };

        i2c@1 {
            #address-cells = <0x01>;
            #size-cells = <0x00>;
            phandle = <0xb3>;
            reg = <0x01>;
        };
    };
```

What is missing?